# Android Bluetooth: IsConnected?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is there a way to figure out if you are connected to a Bluetooth Device?

I have my app connecting, sending/receiving just fine.  However I need a way to see if I'm still connected say.. if I walk out of range and walk back into range.

I noticed there isnt an isConnected function in the Bluetooth Socket, like there is in the TCP stuff... is there a way to see if you are connected, or communicating to the device you're supposed to be connected with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to get around this was to send a "heartbeat" message once per second.  If it doesn't go through, then I assume Bluetooth is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Send the smallest amount of data that you can and see if you get a response.  If you don't, well, you don't have a connection.

Answer (score 0):

The following broadcast receiver values should tell you when any BT device is disconnected:

```
intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED); // API 5
intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED); // API 5
```

You should probably implement a BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener proxy listener if you are interested in a specific device:

```
private class MyBluetoothHeadsetListener //
                implements BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener
{
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy)
    {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.A2DP)
        {
            BluetoothA2dp bluetoothA2dp = (BluetoothA2dp) proxy;
            mDevicesA2dp = bluetoothA2dp.getConnectedDevices();
            for (BluetoothDevice deviceA2dp : mDevicesA2dp)
            {
                boolean isA2dpPlaying = bluetoothA2dp.isA2dpPlaying(deviceA2dp);
            }
            return;
        }

        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET)
        {
            BluetoothHeadset bluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy;
            mDevicesNonA2dp = bluetoothHeadset.getConnectedDevices();
            if (mDevicesNonA2dp.size() > 0)
            {
                for (BluetoothDevice deviceNonA2dp : mDevicesNonA2dp)
                {
                    BluetoothClass bluetoothClass = deviceNonA2dp.getBluetoothClass();
                    String bluetoothDeviceClass = bluetoothClassToString(bluetoothClass);
                    boolean isAudioConnected = bluetoothHeadset.isAudioConnected(deviceNonA2dp);
                }
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

...

private MyBluetoothHeadsetListener mProfileListener = new MyBluetoothHeadsetListener();

...

BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
adapter.getProfileProxy(mApp, mProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
adapter.getProfileProxy(mApp, mProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.A2DP);
```